# Automatically Set Alerts on List

Tags: list, alert

Is it possible to create a workflow or jquery function within the list's page that would allow a user to automatically be signed up for the built-in sharepoint alerts on any item they themselves create in the list?  This can be remedied with a workflow to create our own custom alert emails, but would like to try to implement the built-ins. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer, create a workflow that sends an email to the creator of the item on creation and on item change.  This is out of the box functionality.

> but would like to try to implement the built-ins

Not sure what you mean by that.. unless you mean out of the box.

Comment: I was simply wondering if you were able to automatically set the out of the box alerts. But I will likely just do the aforementioned and just create a fast workflow myself.